# Applying jQuery action to specific control

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many dynamically placed controls on a page, mostly textboxes, that have a class of "dynamic_control". When I move my mouse over each textbox I want only that specific textbox to have a red border. But, right now, ALL textboxes with the "dynamic_control" class are turning red. I know, this is a user error...

```
    $(".dynamic_control").mouseover(function() {
    $(".dynamic_control").css("border-color", "red");
})
```

Yes, I realize it's working exactly like I told it to work. lol....

BUT, how can I have the border-color change for ONLY that specific control. Please keep in mind that all these textboxes/controls are dynamically placed. Thanks!

Comment: `mouseover(function (this) { $(this).css...`

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a red border just when the mouse is on it (hover), right? Use css `hover` pseudo-class like this:

```
.dynamic_control:hover
{
    border-color: red;
}
```

If you don't want css, use [jQuery `hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) instead of `mouseover`. With `mouseover` you are setting a red-border, but you are not removing it when mouse is not on it; that's why all boxes are becoming red. You need to reset the `border-color`.

```
$(".dynamic_control").hover(
    // on mouse over
    function(){
        $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
    },
    // on mouse out
    function(){
        $(this).css('border-color', 'gray');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do need to do something else with the hovered element, the correct syntax would be as follows:

```
$(".dynamic_control").mouseover(function() {
    // Reset the border color of all '.dynamic_control' elements
    $(".dynamic_control").css("border-color", "initial");

    // Make only the hovered element's border-color red
    $(this).css("border-color", "red");
});
```

I'm using your problem as an example, but do use mshsayem's CSS solution, which is the most apporpriate for your case.

Comment: you can also add `$(".dynamic_control").css("border-color", "initial");` to your code to add back inputs initial color once hovered on other inputs

Comment: You are correct, the answer was updated with your suggestion. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`:hover` will work for styling. If you wanted to attach any other Javascript actions to the mouseover, you can address the individual element that triggered the event as shown in this fiddle based on your example:

https://jsfiddle.net/jacobsee/qnun9sr2/